# Univariate time series analysis: sine wave with a constant period?

Tags: time-series

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sine wave with a constant period: what else is constant?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20359/sine-wave-with-a-constant-period-what-else-is-constant)

Which statistic that you can calculate on a window remains constant on a sine wave with a constant period? This is for a window function for a proprietary filter.

Comment: A simple moving average over one full period will remain constant.

Comment: This is your 6th attempt to post a question on an SE site. Could you now take some time to read some of the recommendations that were provided to you and try to add some details to your question? As it stands, it is difficult to tell what is being asked so I'm closing it in the hope you'll be able to add more context.